# My browser doesn't prompt me for access to location when using geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am writing a piece of javascript that retrieves the user's locations using the geolocation api, and displays it on a map using the google maps api. I wrote the code below. It seems to work fine locally, but as soon as i host the code on my website, there is nog longer a prompt for user location (http://lucakleijweg.nl/myLoc.html). Could you help me figure out why?

```
//getting the user's location
window.onload = getMyLocation();

function getMyLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError);
  } else {
    alert ("oops, no geolocation support");
  }
}

function displayLocation(position){
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var div = document.getElementById("location");

  div.innerHTML = "you are at Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude;
  div.innerHTML += " (with " + position.coords.accuracy + " meters accuracy)";
//calculate distance from HQ using user's coordinates
var km = computeDistance(position.coords, ourCoords);
var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
distance.innerHTML = "you are " + km + " km away from the Wickedly Smart HQ";

showMap(position.coords);
}
```

Comment: Check you console: '[blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://lucakleijweg.nl.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to serve your page over `HTTPS` not `HTTP` for the `Geolocation` API:

> Secure context
>
> This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) for reference.